# Google sync tool / Outlook

Tags: outlook, google-apps

I'm having real problems with the Google sync tool and Outlook.

I've run the tool and it creates a duplicate profile. So I added the new data file into Outlook and then copied across emails/folders from my old profile to my new. I then closed Outlook, restarted it and my folder I dragged across has disappeared.

It would be really useful to merge the two profiles together and this obviously isn't the way to do it, so help with recovery and merging would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is struggling to recover lost/deleted emails and wants to do it free - check out this website (http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/restoredeleteditemsfromanoutlookpst.htm). This is a process and uses the MS scan tool but combined with the HEX editor has fixed my problem. I ran this on an Outlook 2013 / downloaded version and it worked fine (outlook 15).